# Reader can't display result

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I made a connection with my database, and I've executed a query for get a result of a specific field of my table but the reader doesn't enter in the while, why?

```
 public void connect()
    {
        string connStr = @"Server=xx98.66;Port=xx6;Database=sxxt;Uid=axx;Pwd=admxxx3z;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();

            string stm = "SELECT lastUpdated from soccerseason WHERE caption = 'Eredivisie 2015/1'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);

            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("stdrstrr" + rdr.GetString(0));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Connection successfull !");

            conn.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Eccezione =>  " + ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the query directly against the database and examined the results? That is the first step. If there is no data, you have solved the problem. There is some reason the reader is not reading through Read().

Comment: There's data in the db

Comment: The code seems to be correct. So, probably there is no data matching your WHERE or you are connecting to a different database

Comment: what about escaping the \ with \\? just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

This will help you I think

Include this

```
using MySql.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.Types;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Change the code slightly and check

```
    {
         string connStr = @"Server=xx98.66;Port=xx6;Database=sxxt;Uid=axx;Pwd=admxxx3z;";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
    {
         string stm = "SELECT lastUpdated from soccerseason WHERE caption = 'Eredivisie 2015/1'";

                    MySqlCommand cmd= conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT lastUpdated from soccerseason WHERE caption = 'Eredivisie 2015/1'";
                    MySqlDataReader rdr;
                    conn.Open();
                    rdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dtsoccer= new DataTable();
                    dtsoccer.Load(rdr);
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtsoccer.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row["lastUpdated "].ToString());
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    Console.ReadKey();

      }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Eccezione =>  " + ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using the same exact query, why the reader should now return some row?